# Cannot override initialiser in subclass of generic class

Tags: swift, generics, subclass

I'd like to make a subclass of a generic class that is itself a subclass but I cannot override the initializer.

To clarify:

```
class BaseClass {

    init(printMe: String) {
        print(printMe)
    }
}

class GenericClass<T>: BaseClass {

    var object: T?
}

class NotGenericClass: GenericClass<NSNumber> {

    override init(printMe: String) {    // <- Error here
        super.init(printMe: printMe)

        // More setup
    }

}

let a = NotGenericClass(printMe: "Print this")
a.object = NSNumber(int: 1)
```

The `override init(printMe: String)` line in NotGenericClass gives the following error:

```
Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
```

If GenericClass did not take a type parameter, this code would work. Is this a bug with Swift or am I misunderstanding how subclassing generic classes should work?

Comment: May we assume you're using Swift 2.0?

Comment: Yes, I am using Swift 2.0

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `GenericClass` doesn't automatically inherit the initializer in this case.

This makes it work:

```
class GenericClass<T>: BaseClass {
    var object: T?
    // Explicitly provide an initializer
    override init(printMe: String) {
        super.init(printMe: printMe)
    }
}
```

This isn't clear from the [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222) section of the docs, which claims that *"If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers"*. You might want to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).